# stripe - tell if a customer has cancelled their credit card

Tags: stripe-payments

How can I tell from the stripe api -

1. A user has cancelled their subscription?
2. A user's credit card is no longer valid.

Is there anyway round having to call the stripe API every time the user logs in to check these facts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling cancellations is purely the responsibility of your application—users don't have an interface to Stripe. If they're canceling, they're doing it through whatever account management system you provide. You should thus be tracking cancellations in your own database. Whatever database you're using, add a subscription status field and update it when a user cancels or re-subscribes.

As for tracking invalid cards, Stripe provides notifications of billing failures—and many other useful events—[via webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). In most cases, if you're not implementing a webhook responder, you're working much too hard on your billing infrastructure. Stripe is built to push a wide variety of information *to* you; polling the API yourself is just overcomplicating things for most purposes.